# GKE Stackdriver not parsing json

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-logging

I have a GKE deployment in the default namespace of my cluster writing json out to stdout. For some reason the lines are being picked up as a textPayload (pasted below) instead of a json payload. Stackdriver is receiving the logs but not parsing the log lines. Anyone know why?

`{
    "textPayload": "{\"timestamp\":\"2018-12-29T04:37:55Z\",\"severity\":\"INFO\",\"httpRequest\":{\"requestMethod\":\"GET\",\"requestUrl\":\"/healthz\",\"status\":\"200\",\"userAgent\":\"kube-probe/1.11+\",\"remoteIp\":\"10.28.5.1:45732\",\"latency\":\"0.000052327s\"},\"message\":\"Completed request\",\"context\":{\"data\":{\"httpRequest\":{\"requestMethod\":\"GET\",\"requestUrl\":\"/healthz\",\"status\":\"200\",\"userAgent\":\"kube-probe/1.11+\",\"remoteIp\":\"10.28.5.1:45732\",\"latency\":\"0.000052327s\"}}}}\n",
    "insertId": "z8530p0phoyggk6w4",
    "resource": {
      "type": "k8s_container",
      "labels": {
        "container_name": "charts",
        "namespace_name": "default",
        "location": "us-central1",
        "project_id": "******",
        "cluster_name": "********",
        "pod_name": "charts-586d4cb4b6-fmw6m"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2018-12-29T04:37:55.920510496Z",
    "severity": "INFO",
    "logName": "projects/******/logs/stdout",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2018-12-29T04:37:58.865021941Z",
    "metadata": {
      "systemLabels": {
        "provider_zone": "us-central1-b",
        "top_level_controller_name": "charts",
        "node_name": "******",
        "container_image": "*******",
        "provider_resource_type": "gce_instance",
        "top_level_controller_type": "Deployment",
        "name": "charts",
        "container_image_id": "*******",
        "service_name": [
          "charts-service"
        ],
        "provider_instance_id": "*********"
      },
      "userLabels": {
        "pod-template-hash": "1428076062",
        "tier": "web",
        "app": "charts"
      }
    }
  }`

What do I need to change so this gets parsed correctly? It's valid json and generated by logrus (and the formater https://github.com/icco/logrus-stackdriver-formatter/blob/sd-v2/formatter.go).

Oh and example log line generated when running locally:

`{"timestamp":"2018-12-29T05:07:31.257829Z","severity":"INFO","httpRequest":{"requestMethod":"GET","requestUrl":"/healthz","status":"200","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.28 Safari/537.36","remoteIp":"[::1]:55033","latency":"0.000052380s"},"message":"Completed request","context":{"data":{"httpRequest":{"requestMethod":"GET","requestUrl":"/healthz","status":"200","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.28 Safari/537.36","remoteIp":"[::1]:55033","latency":"0.000052380s"}}}}`

Answer (score 4):

This is a known bug in GKE: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/121340431

The fix is to change your cluster version.